# I want to replace the custom id of links based on query string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have the following html code in my website (www.mysite.com) :

```
<a href="www.website.com?rh=1234">Link 1</a>
<a href="www.website.com/page/?rh=1234">Lin… 2</a>
```

What I'm trying to do is, **when there is a query string** "r" attached to my website's address example www.mysite.com?r=9876, **the links should change** to:

```
<a href="www.website.com?r=9876">Link 1</a>
<a href="www.website.com/page/?r=9876">Link 2</a>
```

I want to replace 'rh=1234' with 'r=query_string_id' and it should happen only on a particular domain, www.website.com in this case. I guess this is possible with javascript, but I'm not sure how to do it. I found [this](http://www.artisnavi.com/ttaching-custom-ids-to-links-based-on-the-query-string/?ref=single) during my research, but its not exactly what I'm looking for. I want the change to happen only when there is a query string in the in my website's url. Can someone please post a javascript code to make this possible. Also I'm using the blogger platform.

Comment: Your question has already been answered in your previous post that got closed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a[href*=+'YOUR_WEBSITE'+]').each(function() {
    this.href = this.href.split('?rh=').join('?r=');
});
```

Should work if `rh` is the first query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href*="website.com?rh"]').each(function()
{
    var curr_value = $(this).attr('href'); // you dont ectually need this
    var new_value = 'whatever your new links is';
    $(this).attr('href' , $new_value);
});
```